# OpenCV python - Distance from Origin to Harris Corners

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I'm writing a python library to do basic processing on geometric images. One of the desired functions is to return a list of distance of all corners' distance from the origin. I'm struggling with how to do this after looking at the print of my corner objects;

```
[[  9.20031281e+01   9.20031281e+01   9.20031281e+01 ...,   6.66796863e-01
1.01710939e+01   1.01710939e+01]
[  1.36668701e+02   1.36668701e+02   1.36668701e+02 ...,   1.33374023e+00
1.07448441e+02   1.07448441e+02]
[  1.36668701e+02   1.36668701e+02   1.36668701e+02 ...,   1.33374023e+00
1.07448441e+02   1.07448441e+02]
..., 
[ -7.81250012e-04   3.12500005e-03   1.83593743e-02 ...,   3.36616707e+01
2.24355469e+01   2.24355469e+01]
[ -4.88281257e-05   3.12500005e-03   5.41992206e-03 ...,   3.67563972e+01
2.24355469e+01   2.24355469e+01]
[ -4.88281257e-05   5.37109387e-04   5.37109387e-04 ...,   3.67563972e+01
2.24355469e+01   2.24355469e+01]]
```

This image looked like this (note the two pink detected corners);

[image]

How can I find the distance (angle is not required although would be useful too) from origin to the corners?

Thanks!

Comment: where are you defining the origin?

Comment: nowhere, I think the origin is the top left corner (0, 0) by default

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of retrieving the `(x,y)` location of each match. I'll be honest its not the neatest way to do things nor probably the quickest, but it works (also I haven't fine tuned the parameters for detection).

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import math

filename = "/Users/me/Downloads/square.jpg"
img = cv2.imread(filename)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = np.float32(gray)
dst = cv2.cornerHarris(gray,2,3,0.04)

for y in range(0, gray.shape[0]):
 for x in range(0, gray.shape[1]):
  harris = cv2.cv.Get2D(cv2.cv.fromarray(dst), y, x) # get the x,y value
  # check the corner detector response
  if harris[0] > 0.01*dst.max():
   print x,y # these are the locations of the matches
   print 'Distance in pixels from origin: %d' % math.sqrt(x**2+y**2)
   # draw a small circle on the original image
   cv2.circle(img,(x,y),2,(155, 0, 25))

cv2.imshow('Harris', img) # show the image
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: Are you saying I can iterate over cv2 corner objects and access an x and y property?

Comment: I imagine you drew the points by doing something like this `img[dst>0.01*dst.max()]=[0,0,255]`, wouldn't this let you get the x and y of the pixel? (haven't got opencv here to test)

Comment: I just tried it, corners have no explicit x and y property that be accessed like that

Comment: i'm not sure exactly what that bit from the tutorial does. it does draw on the corners though. using nano as my editor so can't explore the properties unfortunately

Comment: okay, when i get to work ill edit the answer. in short you just need to convert the 1D index from my comment above to an `(i,j)`, easy enough to look up/do.

Comment: could you link me something useful? i've been looking for a while and I'm not sure if there's anything that makes total sense to me

Comment: i found it actually confusing and harder than id have expected based of my previous opencv usage (there were no terribly useful links). i updated with a small example.

Comment: thanks for that chris, I'll let you know how I get on!

Comment: it appears to be taking several minutes to perform this over a 240x360 image (it's a raspberry pi which won't help!) why do you think this is? any suggestions

Comment: it took a while on my laptop too (20 seconds) on small images. id say its a combination of coverting the array to a cvMat for each iterated element and the double for loop. there could be a more native bumpy way of doing this kind of thing, but if speed is an issue consider c++. similar code as its mainly calling opencv functions.

Comment: there must be a way, it draws on the corners to an image instantly using img[dst>0.01*dst.max()]=[0,0,255]. thanks for help anyway, let me know if you come up with anything faster :)

Comment: if you're interested I find an easier (and much faster!) way to do this is through the method I posted in my answer - via shi-tomasi good features to track instead!

Answer (score 0):

I revisited this after a while and found that the Shi-Tomasi method allowed much more obvious and, most importantly, faster access to the corner coordinates.

```
corners = cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack(image, 4, 0.5, 10)
```

Will fill corners, parameters explained in docs, then;

```
for i in self.new_corners: #draws on corners
    x,y = i.ravel()
```

Will expose coordinates per iteration.

I'm sure this is possible via corner harris too, I just can't find anything which describes the object which it creates.